# OpenLayers DrawFeature control with Point destroys double click to zoom

Tags: javascript, event-handling, openlayers

I have some simple code that I copied from one of the openlayers examples for drawing several different types of geometries on the map.  The problem is, whenever the "point" geometry is selected, I lose the ability to double-click to zoom in.  The only difference between the examples and my code is I'm registering the handlers to use MOD_SHIFT, because i want to retain the ability to pan/zoom.  Here is a snipit of code:

```
   point: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(this.geometryFilterLayer,
                            OpenLayers.Handler.Point, 

                            {
                                'done':  console.info("drew point")
                            },

                            {
                                keyMask: OpenLayers.Handler.MOD_SHIFT
                            }
                            ),
                        polygon: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(this.geometryFilterLayer,
                            OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon, 
                            {
                                'done':  console.info("drew polygon")
                            },

                            {
                                keyMask: OpenLayers.Handler.MOD_SHIFT
                            }
                            ),
```

The funny thing about the above code is, the 'done' event only gets fired when the control/handler is created, and the keyMask doesn't work at all -- I have to loop through this object and manually set the keyMask each time, but that's not the real problem at hand.

I've tried every way I can think of to register a dblclick event, but no matter what, I can't get it to zoom in when I double click.  It works fine on all the other geometries (bbox, point/radius, and polygon).

Can anybody give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

I never solved this issue, but ended up doing away with using MOD_XXX altogether.  Each different draw control had too much built-in functionality for what happens when you hold shift, ctrl, alt, etc.  I ended up using custom Buttons and a toolbar, that way the user can explicitly select the drawing control themselves.

```
this.toolbar = new OpenLayers.Control.Panel({
                displayClass: 'olControlEditingToolbar'
            });
            map.addControl(this.toolbar);

var navButton = new OpenLayers.Control.Button({
                displayClass: "olControlNavigation", 
                title: "Navigation",
                trigger: lang.hitch(this, function(data){
                    this.toggleDrawControl("navigation");

                    navButton.activate();
                    pointButton.deactivate();
                    bboxButton.deactivate();
                    pointRadiusButton.deactivate();
                    polygonButton.deactivate();
                })
            }); 

...

this.toolbar.addControls([navButton, pointButton, bboxButton, pointRadiusButton, polygonButton]);
```

and my function to toggle draw controls (can be called externally, so that's why I re-call the activate and deactivate functions:

```
 toggleDrawControl: function(geometryType){
            this.currentGeometryType = geometryType;
            for(key in this.drawControls) {
                var control = this.drawControls[key];
                if(geometryType == key) {
                    control.activate();
                    this.drawingButtons[key].activate();
                } else {
                    control.deactivate();
                    this.drawingButtons[key].deactivate();
                }
            }
        }
```